# Number of affected rows while running FTS query

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

Recently we've encountered a strange phenomenon, we have an ordinary query in a FTS structure:

```
select top 50 from TABLE where contains (COLUMN, 'string*')
```

Although the query is written with `top 50` phrase we still see in the rowcount column, at the profiler high number of affected rows.

When we ran the query in yhe mgmt studio only relevant rows are returned.

Is this normal behavior of full test search?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have other operations in the same procedure?

The RowCounts will include affected counts from other operations as well. For example, the following will return 13 in the `SQL:BatchCompleted` event.  If you capture the `SQL:StmtCompleted` event as well you'll the discrete counts in RowCounts prior to this 13 sum:

```
declare @t table (i int)
insert into @t
       select 1 union all
       select 2 union all
       select 3;

select top 5 *
from dbo.YourTable;

select top 5 *
from dbo.YourOtherTable;
```

Comment: Nope, it is just a simple select with contains syntax .

Comment: Thanks for the help I've just realized the query runs on a view which have 2 computed columns .